# Partial application of protocol method is not allowed

Tags: methods, swift, closures, protocols, xcode6-beta7

Can someone explain this error and why this works with closure?

If you change 'Test' to 'A' inside 'B' class everything works in both cases.

beta 7

```
protocol Test {
    func someFunc() -> String
    var someClosure: () -> Int { get }
}

class A: Test {
    func someFunc() -> String {
        return "A String"
    }

    var someClosure: () -> Int {
        return {
            return 2
        }
    }
}

class B {
    let a: Test
    let aString: () -> String
    let aInt: () -> Int

    init(a: Test){
        self.a = a

        aString = a.someFunc // Error: Partial application of protocol method is not allowed
        aInt = a.someClosure // Works fine
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also here is my weird segmentation fault collection https://gist.github.com/aleksgapp/795a2d428008bdfa4823

Do not hesitate to comment if you have some thoughts about any.

Comment: Since Xcode7 beta 2 this is working

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE** (thanks to Laszlo Korte)

> From Xcode 7 Beta 2 with Swift 2.0 Release Notes: Non-mutating methods
>   of structs, enums, and protocols may now be partially applied to their
>   “self” parameter.

For example:

```
let a: Set<Int> = [1, 2] 
let b: [Set<Int>] = [[1], [3]]

b.map(a.union) // [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (correct for Xcode 6 with Swift 1.2)

Protocol can be adopted by class, **structure** or **enumeration**. In last two cases partial application of structure or enumeration method is not allowed and you get "Partial application of protocol method is not allowed" because `a: Test` can be structure or enumeration.

Partially applied method or function is in other words `curried method or function`. So when you write `a.someFunc` you try to partially apply this method, i.e. get reference to closure that implicitly holds reference to `a`. But structures and enumerations are not reference types, they are value types and there are no reference to `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I think it's sad though.

Comment: With Xcode7 beta 2 this has been changed to work now: "Non-mutating methods of structs, enums, and protocols may now be partially applied to their “self”
parameter."

Answer (score 3):

So, I can't speak to *why* it behaves like this, but I did find a workaround.
Try this:

```
aString = { return a.someFunc() }
```

Comment: Worked for me! Awesome.